# NSEvent and Magic Mouse

Tags: macos, osx-lion, mouse, trackpad

How do I distinguish whether the event `-(void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event` was triggered by a Magic Mouse or a trackpad?

The reason I'm asking this question is because I want to assign a different action to the scrolling event when a trackpad is used because the user can pinch to zoom on the trackpad. On the magic mouse, however, the user can't pinch easily, so I want to use the scrolling function as a substitute for pinching.

I can distinguish between a normal mouse and a Magic Mouse using this line:

```
if (([event momentumPhase] != NSEventPhaseNone) || [event phase] != NSEventPhaseNone)
```

However this test is passed for both, trackpad and Magic Mouse.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to distinguish between a scroll wheel on a mouse (not a Magic Mouse, but I suspect it will still work) and a trackpad using NSEvent's subtype:

```
enum {
   NSMouseEventSubtype           = NX_SUBTYPE_DEFAULT,
   NSTabletPointEventSubtype     = NX_SUBTYPE_TABLET_POINT,
   NSTabletProximityEventSubtype = NX_SUBTYPE_TABLET_PROXIMITY
   NSTouchEventSubtype             = NX_SUBTYPE_MOUSE_TOUCH
};
```

Comment: I don't think this works for Magic Mouse - it has the same subtype as track pad.

Comment: Did you figure this out?
It seems that inside scrollWheel there is no way to find out if the event came from the trackpad or the magic mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle `scrollWheel` for the Magic Mouse and add a `NSMagnificationGestureRecognizer` for the pinch gesture on the trackpad. The two do not conflict with each-other but the swipe-scroll on the trackpad will trigger `scrollWheel`.