# How to find out that the NSEvent click event is from a mouseClick or trackpad Click?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

I can check the NSScrollWheel  event from a mouse or a trackpad:

[Mac Cocoa: How to differentiate if a NSScrollWheel event is from a mouse or trackpad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807616/mac-cocoa-how-to-differentiate-if-a-nsscrollwheel-event-is-from-a-mouse-or-trac)

But it is possible to check a mouse click, also a NSEvent is from a mouse or trackpad? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check "**event.subtype**" to see from which device it came.

If it's a mouse, the "subtype" value should be **NSMouseEventSubtype**. If it's not a mouse, the value will be something else (e.g.: **NSApplicationActivatedEventType** or **NSTouchEventSubtype**).