# Determine if trackpad exists on macOS

Tags: macos, appkit, trackpad, cgeventtap

Is there an API in AppKit (or elsewhere) to determine if a device has a trackpad connected and enabled? I need my application to enable different behaviours on scroll events depending on whether they are coming from a two finger natural scroll gesture on a trackpad or from a vertical only scroll on a traditional mouse.

Going over the documentation, I cannot find anything and Googling didn't seem to reveal anything either.

I am using an event tap currently to receive events (also, please note that I have very little native macOS development experience so don't assume a lot of prior knowledge)

Comment: Do you want to determine if a trackpad is connected or do you want to determine if the scrollwheel event is coming from a trackpad?

Comment: now that i think of it, both would be useful. if no trackpad is connected, I can setup a specific behaviour but i guess a user can have both a trackpad and mouse connected at the same time so it would be useful to know where each even came from as well.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out a solution to part of my problem (which is highlighted by Willeke in the comments above) can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42747641/56242

Since that doesn't offer a solution for checking if a trackpad is enabled on the system, I will not mark this as the accepted solution, even though it turns out it works for my particular use case, since someone else might come across this question and that solution doesn't fit their